# DNS Setup - 1 application across multiple domains

Tags: php, dns, cname, multiple-domains

I've created an application using PHP and MySQL. I would like to setup access to the system across multiple domains. The application is hosted on my own domain and I'd like to use a CNAME for each customer to access it.

Customer A: http://myapp.domain-a.com
Customer B: http://system.domain-b.co.uk

Can anyone give me some guidance on how I can achieve this please.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this via DNS hook of the domain(s). For example: 
Change the DNS Settings of `domain-b.co.uk` and edit the corresponding DNS entry (**CNAME**) of the subdomain `system` and change the **Alias-Name** for this subdomain (`system.domain-b.co.uk`) to `domain-a.com`.

Now all requests to `system.domain-b.co.uk` get redirected to your server at `domain-a.com`. Then you just have to make sure that the server behind `domain-a.com` accepts requests from `system.domain-b.co.uk` by adding an vhost **OR** route all incoming requests of this machine by default to the vhost of `myapp.domain-a.com` if no alternative route is defined.

Pros of using a Alias-Name (instead of using a static IP address): if the IP Address of `domain-a.com` changes, you don't have to edit the settings of `system.domain-b.co.uk`.

*PS: DNS Changes may take up to 24-48 hours coming into effect*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think I've explained it 100% though. The subdomains I mentioned at first were for two seperate customers, I didn't mention where the files were hosted. I think I understand your suggestion although I don't host my system myself, meaning I don't have access to any apache configuration files. The files are hosted on my site which has Cpanel. I need to be able to point **myapp.domain-a.com** to **app.myhosteddomain.com** and **system.domain-b.co.uk** to **app.myhosteddomain.com**.